# How to embed HTML code into WordPress mail

Tags: php, wordpress, email

I am having issues with embedding a html body into my WordPress mail. As of now I have tried multiple code snippets and none seem to work.

What I am seeing right now is, that the email is being sent correctly, but the html code is typed in as text and not being displayed as html content.

I have included my code below

```
// Get the Customer billing email
$billing_email  = $order->get_billing_email();
$subject = 'Your Email Subject';

 // Message
 $message = '
 <html><body><p>Here are the birthdays upcoming in August!</p></body></html>
';

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');


wp_mail( $billing_email, $subject, $message );
```

I tried using some other code snippets I found on stackoverflow, and none of them have worked

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2):

This code now works I just needed to change the content type from text to html.

```
  // Get the Customer billing email
$billing_email  = $order->get_billing_email();
$subject = 'Your Email Subject';

 // Message
 $message = '
 <html><body><p>Here are the birthdays upcoming in August!</p></body></html>
';

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be setremove_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'set_html_content_type' );
add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'set_html_content_type' );
function set_html_content_type() {

    return 'text/html';
}


wp_mail( $billing_email, $subject, $message );
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, you missed headers to add wp_mail function call. You declared but not used.

```
$to = 'sendto@example.com';
$subject = 'The subject';
$body = 'The email body content';
$headers = array( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' );
 
wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers );
```